# How can I override a single line of a class function without having to copy over the entire function into the child class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class A():
    def parsing_tasks(self):
        self.start = start(self)
        ....
        self.end = end_stage(self)

@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    def DAG(self):
        dag = self.parsing_tasks()
        return dag


@dataclasses.dataclass
class C(B):
    def parsing_tasks(self):    <-- I am overriding this function form class A
        self.start = start(self)
        ...
        self.end = end_stage_by_mic(self)


def end_stage(dag_def: B):
    ....
    return end
    
def end_stage_by_mic(dag_def: A):
    ....
    return end_by_mic
```

What i would like to do is to have a `self.end = end_stage_by_mic(self)` in `class C`, as I do above, but the issue is that the function `parsing_tasks` is very very long, and it seems extremely wasteful to need to copy over the entire function in class C, in order the override the function in class A, when all I am changing is one line inside `parsing_tasks`, the one line being `self.end`.

One typical way to do it is to parameterise the base class instead of reproducing the whole function, but the issue is that you will notice that in the arguments of `end_stage` and `end_stage_by_mic`, they reference classes A and B, so moving the two functions `end_stage` and `end_stage_by_mic` creates other issues.

Any ideas how else to do it?

Comment: I suppose you could call `super().parsing_tasks()` and then do `self.end = end_stage_by_mic(self)`, thereby throwing away the one from A, assuming `end_stage` doesn't do anything dangerous.

Comment: You should refactor the methods in the base class to be more specific, so you can override where you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Barmar, could you give an example, I'm not quite sure what you mean by refactor!

Comment: You need an `end_stage()` method on `A` which you override in `C`.

Comment: Make `start()` and `end_stage()` methods, so you call `self.start()` and `self.end_stage()`. Then you only need to override `end_stage()` in the subclass.[

Comment: I'm not following. Inside `parsing_tasks` there are lots and lots of function calls. 
`end_stage()` is currently a method? Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Is it possible to post a solution? Sorry if I'm slow on this - still relatively new to classes and functions.

Comment: Ignore me, got it. Thank you!